# Graphs which can connect every pair of vertices via a hamilton path

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Let G be a simple undirected Graph with the following property : For every pair of
 vertices $(u,v)$, there is a hamilton path from $u$ to $v$. It is clear that 
 all complete graphs have this property and that the graph must have a hamilton
 circle to have this property.

A hamilton path is a path visiting EVERY vertex exactly once.
 A hamilton circle is a circle containing EVERY vertex.

- Is there a name for such graphs ?
- Which graphs beside the complete ones have this property (Is there a nice criterion) ?
- What is the least possible number of edges for a  graph with $n$ vertices to have this
  property ?

Comment: I don't think a Hamiltonian circuit is a necessary consequence, if we mean the same thing when we say that. Consider the graph on a,b,c where a is adjacent to b and c. Eg b-a-c. There is a Hamiltonian path from each vertex to every other vertex, but there is no Hamiltonian circuit on the graph.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes this quite a bit more interesting.

Comment: If a graph has the given property, it is $3$-connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the answers so far address the minimum number of edges required for an $n$-vertex graph with this property.

It is easy to see that (provided $n>3$) that there can be no vertex of degree $2$. If there is, say $u$ has neighbours $v,w$, then the only path from $v$ to $w$ which uses $u$ is the path $vuw$, which is not Hamilton.

So we have all degrees at least $3$, and so the minimum number is at least $3n/2$.

In face for any even $n=6,10,14,\ldots$ there is a suitable graph with this many vertices. Suppose $n=2k$, with $k$ odd. We claim that the prism (two $k$-cycles, with edges between corresponding vertices) is such a graph. Given any start and end vertices which are not corresponding vertices on the two cycles (that case is easy), we start from one and move round the cycles towards the other, alternating between cycles, until we are about to hit the end vertex. Instead, we now stick to one cycle, go past it until we get almost back to the starting point, flip to the other cycle and then come back. This is illustrated for a particular pair on the left, going anticlockwise round the cycles. However, this may not work due to parity constraints: if this alternating movement would hit the end vertex from the wrong direction, we can't just stop and go past it. If this happens, we can just go round the cycle in the other direction (right example) and $k$ being odd will ensure that this works.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Few years over date, but given that the answer by Mateusz seems wrong: these graphs are named Hamiltonian-connected graphs and some sufficient conditions can be found in section 3.2 of this [dissertation](https://scholarworks.wmich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3965&context=dissertations). The variants on Dirac's, Ore's, and Posa's theorems are a bit stricter.

Update:
For example the equivalent of Dirac's theorem is: If G is a graph of size $n\geq3$ such that $\sigma \geq \frac{n+1}{2}$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian connected. (Where $\sigma \geq \frac{n}{2}$ is enough for Hamiltonicity).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: As others say, it would be good to state (some of) the results from the dissertation you link to. However, I think this is a valuable answer. Note that the older answer is incorrect, and that this is so far the only one which answers the first part of the question ("is there a name for this?").

Comment: I answer 2 out of his 3 questions, where his second question is way too broad to give a concise answer and the only existing answer was incorrect. There are lots of sufficient criteria which can easily be found using the name of these graphs. I added 1 example to make it a stand alone answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Which graphs beside the complete ones have this property? (Is there a nice criterion?)"

About the criterion: I can think of every graph that fulfills Pós' theorem, Ore's theorem or Dirac's theorem conditions (because Ore's theorem implies Pós' theorem and Dirac's theorem is conclusion from Ore's theorem).

I will just prove that for Pós theorem (because I can't find it on the Internet so I think it might be hard to find it for you too):

Let $  D_n(G)= \left \{ v\in V: deg_G(v)\leq n \right \}$

Pós' theorem states that: $G$ is a graph with $p$ vertices. If for every $1\leq n < \frac {p-1}{2}$,  $D_n(G)<n$ (and for $n=\frac{p-1}{2}$, $D_n(G)\leq n$ if $p$ is odd number) then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

It is easy to prove then that every two vertices in $G$ are ends of a Hamiltonian path (I won't prove the whole theorem here).

Proof: If the theorem is false then there exists counterexamples. Let $H$ be the maximal counterexample to the theorem (that means that adding any new edge to $H$ makes it Hamiltonian). Because adding edges doesn't change Pós condition and makes H Hamiltonian, we proved that every two vertices in H must be ends of some Hamiltonian path.
$\square$

Comment: There are two things that are unclear to me : 1) Is H (the maximal counterexample) non-hamiltonian ? Then pos condition cannot hold. 2) Did you consider the case, when the vertices are already neighbours ? Then the edge between these vertices cannot be add. Perhaps your definition of hamiltonian path is different from mine : A hamiltonian path must visit EVERY vertex exactly once.

Comment: @Peter: H is the maximal counterexample that fulfills Pós condition and is non-hamiltonian. If the theorem is false it must exist, since we are talking about graphs with finite sets of vertices. 2) I have the same definition of Hamiltonian path and I don't quite understand your question. If two vertices are neigbors it's quite clear that you can't add a new edge between them. But it doesn't mean Hamiltonian path between them doesn't exist - just take a look at a simple cycle $C_n$. You can construct hamiltonian path between every two neigbors.

Comment: This is definitely not correct. For example, the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ fulfils Dirac's condition, but any Hamilton path must start and finish in different parts.